# How to skip to next row w/o go through entire for..loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, dataset

i want to skip to next row in below statement

```
For iRow = 0 To dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
     rowDiscnt = dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)

     If rowdiscnt.Item("x") = "S" Then
         'skip to next row
     Else
         'continue loop
     End If

'do something...
Next
```

how to skip to next row w/o go through the entire loop?

Comment: @chinna_82 using break will break you out of the loop, not move to the next iteration.  You might want to look into the [Continue statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Continue For` is the statement you need, like this:

```
For iRow = 0 To dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    rowDiscnt = dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)

    If rowdiscnt.Item("x") = "S" Then
        ' Skip to next iteration of For loop
        Continue For
    Else
        ' Keep doing work in this iteration of the For loop
    End If

    'do something...
Next
```

Comment: @user2412351 - sorry I had originally wrote it backwards, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
For iRow = 0 To dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
     rowDiscnt = dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)

     If rowdiscnt.Item("x") = "S" Then
         break;//'skip to next row
     Else
         'continue loop
     End If

'do something...
Next
```

EDIT

```
For iRow = 0 To dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
     rowDiscnt = dsDiscnt.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)

     If rowdiscnt.Item("x") = "S" Then
         Continue For;//'skip to next row
     Else
         'continue loop
     End If

'do something...
Next
```

Comment: Break will exit the loop entirely, not move it onto its next iteration.

Comment: you can use continue.